# Display images in div with preg_match or preg_replace

Tags: php, image, curl, preg-replace, preg-match-all

my codes here ;

```
$curl = curl_init($link);
    $userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

$html= curl_close($curl);   

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$regex = '/<div id="urunid">(.*?)<\/div>/s';

if ( preg_match_all($regex, $page, $regs1, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) ) {
    echo  preg_replace('<img(.*)src="([^ "]*)"([^>]*)>', '<a href="$2"><img$1src="$2"$3></a>', "", $regs1[0])."<br />";
} else {
    print "Not found";  
}
```

why i can not display images in the div? i want display only images with links in the div but it show nothing i dont know why.. are my codes wrong ? or must i add another function ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$curl = curl_init($link);
    $userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

$html= curl_close($curl);   

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$regex = '/<div id="urunid">(.*?)<\/div>/s';

if ( preg_match_all($regex, $page, $regs1, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) ) {
    echo  preg_replace('<img(.*)src="([^ "]*)"([^>]*)>', '<a href="$2"><img$1src="$2"$3></a>', $regs1[0])."<br />";
} else {
    print "Not found";  
}
```

The problem is that the function `preg_replace()` works like this:

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

First argument : You are giving `'<img(.*)src="([^ "]*)"([^>]*)>'` as pattern, wich is OK.
Second argument is replacement `'<a href="$2"><img$1src="$2"$3></a>'` OK
Third argument should be the subject in wich replacement occurs. You were giving an empty string.

I suggest that you read PHP doc about [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php%20preg_replace()), especialy the section about "$subject" and how returned values work.

Hope it helps